# Spannable string with control character

Tags: android, textview

I want to show a text in a `TextView` with different colors and put control characters to break lines `\n` and tabs `\t\t`...

I do this...

```
SpannableStringBuilder   sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("");
ForegroundColorSpan fcs_red = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED); 
ForegroundColorSpan fcs_blu = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE); 

...
for(int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++)
{
    if(columns[j].equals("<")) continue;

    if(columns[j].contains("/") && columns[j].contains(":"))
    {
        columns[j] = columns[j].replace("<TD>", "\n");
        sb_aux = new SpannableStringBuilder(columns[j]);
        sb_aux.setSpan(fcs_red, 0, sb_aux.length(),Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }
    else
    {
        if(columns[j].contains("<TD>"))
        {
            columns[j] = columns[j].replace("<TD>", "\n\t\t");
            sb_aux = new SpannableStringBuilder(columns[j]);
            sb_aux.setSpan(fcs_blu, 0, sb_aux.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }
        else
        {
            columns[j] = "\n\t\t"+columns[j];
            sb_aux = new SpannableStringBuilder(columns[j]);
            sb_aux.setSpan(fcs_blu, 0, sb_aux.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    sb.append(sb_aux);
}
myTextView.setText(sb);
```

So, the first part of text is showed in RED as expected, but the rest of text do not alternate in RED or  BLUE as expected and the `\n` and `\t` was not recognized

My intention was spanning text in pieces and appending to a `SpannableStringBuilder` to be showed in `TextView`, any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code you can show rich text in a `TextView`.

```
String html = "<font color='red'>This is red</font>" +
              "<br/>new line \t some indent <b>BOLD</b>";

myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```